# How to change the default database location in postgresql.?

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working with PostgreSQL-flask on a windows machine. i wanted to change the default database location into a  project data folder, in my project directory, just for this project. I prefer all my project files in a single directory. In mongoDb i wrote a batch file, with a single line

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath C:\projects\project XXX\project-data\db --journal
```

How can I do this with PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

Change your postgresql.conf

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html

> data_directory (string)
>       Specifies the directory to use for data storage. This parameter can only be set at server start.

You also can create new TableSpace

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html

```
CREATE TABLESPACE fastspace LOCATION '/ssd1/postgresql/data';
```

and create new tables there

```
SET default_tablespace = fastspace ;
CREATE TABLE foo(i int);
```

Comment: And also [new database cluster](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/creating-cluster.html) to keep all files together.

Comment: @Abelisto yes, that sound better.

Comment: frm-doc
Even though located outside the main PostgreSQL data directory, tablespaces
are an integral part of the database cluster and cannot be treated as an au
tonomous collection of data files. They are dependent on metadata contained
n the main data directory, and therefore cannot be attached to a different
database cluster or backed up individually. Similarly, if you lose a tablespace
(file deletion, disk failure, etc), the database cluster might become unreadable
or unable to start. Placing a tablespace on a temporary file system like a RAM
disk risks the reliability of the entire cluster.

Comment: [ cont..] So what's the point.  In mongodb, when you set your data directory as a folder, you can copy and  move  the folder, and your database still works.  That's what i wanted with PostgreSQL.. May not be possible after all. I'm gonna Stick with the default for now.

Comment: Creating a new Database Cluster may be a solution, +1 for that  Abelisto

Answer (score 0):

You need to add entry in server configuration file[server configuration](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html)

> data_directory (string)

Specifies the directory to use for data storage. This parameter can only be set at server start.